# Primefaces datatable rowReorder get row

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to get the row object, in my case of class Story.class, while reordering a row in a primefaces datable. The indexes, which I get from a ReorderEvent, unfortunately are not enough since I have more then one datatable where I would like to reuse the same rowReorder listener.

Here some code fragments:

```
<p:ajax event="rowReorder"
                listener="#{reorderStoryView.onRowReorder}" />
```

The following code line returns null:

```
Story story2 = context.getApplication().
      evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{story}", Story.class);
```

The following code line returns not the current rowData, have problems to determine which row data I get:

```
Story story =(Story)((DataTable)event.getComponent()).getRowData();
```

Can't find any additional information about this problem, maybe you can help me out.

Thx in advance

/d

Comment: For determining what datatable the event comes from: You explicitly cast to a Datatable. Why not use the id of that datatable?

Comment: Thought about it, as primarily backend developer I have some concerns about this solution and further I wasn't able to define numeric values in the id field of the datatable. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the source table adding this line to your listener code:

```
String source = ((DataTable)event.getSource()).getClientId();
```

An example listener method:

```
public void onRowReorder(ReorderEvent event) {
    int from = event.getFromIndex();
    int to = event.getToIndex();
    // the source table
    String source = ((DataTable)event.getSource()).getClientId();
    // Or String source =  event.getComponent().getClientId();
    // Access from backing bean (require reordering in backing bean)
    // reorderStoryView.stories.get(from)
    // reorderStoryView.stories.get(to)
    // Access to the moved row from table component
    DataTable myDatatable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getViewRoot().findComponent(source);
    Story story = myDatatable.getRowData(); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, your commented (optional) solution does not work. I"m not able to determine which list the indexes belong to.
Your primarily solution throws a NullPointerException since

    DataTable myDatatable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getViewRoot().findComponent(source);

returns null. Guess I already tried this or similar solutions ...

Comment: All the shown code should run smoothly, if not there are some hidden issues somewhere in your code. Which is the returned value in your case for `source` string variable?

Comment: I put the datatable component inside a tab of an accordion component, does that eventually change the behaviour?

Comment: But, which is the returned value? This value will you open the door for acting depending on the source table, wherever it be in the component tree.

Comment: Looks ok, its exactly the id of the first <div> element of the table.

    <table ..>
      <tbody><tr><td><div id="j_idt40:0:storiesTable">
    ....

    source = j_idt40:0:storiesTable

Comment: So based on this string you know the source table, don't you? And then could access the row data on the appropriate table using if/then/else blocks.